# PHP - Pass information from an input to php file

Tags: php, forms, post

That's how I'm doing the input in html file:

```
<form action="simplehtmlfile.php" method="post">
  Link da pagina dos Concursos encerrados: <input type="text" name="concursos"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And that's how I'm doing in php file:

```
$htmlbusca = $_POST['concursos']; 
$html=file_get_html($htmlbusca);
```

In php file I'm using the link from input to add 20 rows in database. But I don't know how, sometimes insert 20, sometimes 5, sometimes 16.. It's doing in a random way that I don't understand. It's like, while the code it's getting the information he puts it in the database, but if thinks faster, it stops and don't put all the information... I don't know.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? How why this happens?

---

```
foreach($num as $val):
    if(is_array($val)  && is_array($valorarray) && is_array($entradasarray) && is_array($tituloarray)  && is_array($texarray)  && is_array($realizadorarray)):
       foreach($val as $v):

            $insert="INSERT into spec_insert( entradas, designers,valor_premio, titulo, categoria, textura, realizador) VALUES ('".$entradasarray[$i]."','".$v."','".$valorarray[$i]."','".$tituloarray[$i]."','".$categoriaarray[$i]."','".$texarray[$i]."','".$realizadorarray[$i]."');";
            $sql=mysql_query($insert);

        endforeach;

    else:
         $insert="INSERT into spec_insert( entradas, designers,valor_premio, titulo, categoria, textura, realizador) VALUES ('".$entradasarray[$i]."','".$v."','".$valorarray[$i]."','".$tituloarray[$i]."','".$categoriaarray[$i]."','".$texarray[$i]."','".$realizadorarray[$i]."');";
            $sql=mysql_query($insert);
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Here is the SQL in php file... But that's not the problem... Because as I said the insert in the database was fine, when I had the variable "$html" written in php file:`$html = file_get_html("http://99designs.pt/logo-design/contests?show=finished");`
But now I'm trying to input this variable by the html file.

Comment: Before I add the html file with the input. I had a variable with link, and everything worked fine.

Comment: I don't see any SQL there... How can we know what you're doing wrong if you don't show us what you're doing at all?

Comment: show us your php code.

Comment: I edited the Question with some of php code. I can show all the code, but there's much of the code that is unnecessary understand.. cause it worked fine...

Comment: what exactly are you adding to the database? entire web pages? it's possible that the pages contain code that is breaking your statements, such as semicolons if there is javascript in them

Comment: no, I'm adding this: http://gyazo.com/e08dcaa4967a1887df8b5eb4b5e99b46
Informations that I get from some elements of the page.

What I don't understand is that it works fine, if I simply put the link directly in the code. When I use the input they don't insert all the rows